# How to user Counter() to count the unigram, bigram, cooc and wordcount with a list traning_data?

Tags: python, nlp

I want to know how to user Counter() to count the unigram, bigram, cooc and wordcount with a list traning_data.

I'm a python newcomer,please be patient to me.Thanks!

You need to implement two parts of the HMM postagger.

1. A HMM model
2. viterbi decoding
   This is the code:

   ```
   from collections import Counter
   from math import log

   class HMM(object):
       def __init__(self, epsilon=1e-5, training_data=None):
           self.epsilon = epsilon
           if training_data is not None:
               self.fit(training_data)
   def fit(self, training_data):
   '''
   Counting the number of unigram, bigram, cooc and wordcount from the training
   data.

   Parameters
   ----------
   training_data: list
       A list of training data, each element is a tuple with words and postags.
   '''
   self.unigram = Counter()    # The count of postag unigram, e.g. unigram['NN']=5
   self.bigram = Counter()     # The count of postag bigram, e.g. bigram[('PRP', 'VV')]=1
   self.cooc = Counter()       # The count of word, postag, e.g. cooc[('I', 'PRP')]=1
   self.wordcount = Counter()  # The count of word, e.g. word['I']=1

   print('building HMM model ...')
   for words, tags in training_data:
       # Your code here! You need to implement the ngram counting part. Please count
       # - unigram
       # - bigram
       # - cooc
       # - wordcount

   print('HMM model is built.')
   self.postags = [k for k in self.unigram]
   ```

This is the training_dataset and the expected result as below:

```
    # The tiny example.
    training_dataset = [(['dog', 'chase', 'cat'], ['NN', 'VV', 'NN']),
                (['I', 'chase', 'dog'], ['PRP', 'VV', 'NN']),
                (['cat', 'chase', 'mouse'], ['NN', 'VV', 'NN'])
               ]

    hmm = HMM(training_data=training_dataset)

    # Testing if the parameter are correctly estimated.
    assert hmm.unigram['NN'] == 5
    assert hmm.bigram['VV', 'NN'] == 3
    assert hmm.bigram['NN', 'VV'] == 2
    assert hmm.cooc['dog', 'NN'] == 2
```

Comment: Hello!  I'd recommend updating your title to be more descriptive so this post gets more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Counter()` with a list is pretty straight-forward.
[`Counter.update()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update) does exactly what you need.

---

```
from nltk.util import bigrams

...

for words, tags in training_data:
            self.unigram.update(tags)
            self.bigram.update(bigrams(tags))
            self.cooc.update(zip(words,tags))
            self.wordcount.update(words)
...
```